# PHP Regular expression to check 3 digits followed by alpha

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate a string if and only if meets two conditions:

a. String is exactly 7 characters in length

b.The string format is NNNANNA (N represents digit(0-9) and A alphabet(a-z,A-Z).

Currently I am doing this:

```
if(preg_match('^d{3}\[a-zA-Z]\d{2}\[a-zA-Z]$', $str) and strlen($str)==7)
{
do something
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in
>   C:\wamp\www\warrant\yourproducts\let.php on line 2

What am I missing?

P.S I am horrible with reg expressions.

Ahmar

Comment: Error seems clear, no delimiter was found. See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. It should be:

```
'/^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]\d{2}[a-zA-Z]$/'
```

OR

```
'/^\d{3}[a-z]\d{2}[a-z]$/i'
```

Comment: lol I really am a noob with regexprs. Thanks it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
'/^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]\d{2}[a-zA-Z]$/'
```